# Development environment for a LAMP-based website - Redirects to Server Default Page

Tags: php

In our current environment, if any changes need to be made to the code, these changes are directly coded and updated to the Live server. GWe would like to set-up a development server where we can test our changes before uploading to the live site.

I have attempted to build a development site locally by installing Apache, PHP & MySQL and copying all the htdocs to the Apache folder. However, when I try to access localhost/ it redirects me to the server default page. Any ideas on why this may be happening?

Comment: have you tried accessing localhost/index.php (insert your index filename here) OR 127.0.0.1/index.php?

Comment: Respond to answers by writing "comments", and please leave out greetings and such. Stack Overflow is not a message board.

Answer (score 2):

Have you setup [Apache VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html) and configured it for your sites Document Root?

I would look into your production site and see what's configured.

Also note that when you're setting up a dev/prod environment you will need not just PHP/Apache/etc.. install but also any packages/mods/libs that they are using installed as well.

For Example: if you're using Mod-Re-Write with Apache you need to install and enable it